# How to do a dataTable containing a subtable with Primefaces in the same row? What's doing with mine?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

Look at the behavior of my table, I want that the lines of field email appear inside of the field Email and not like that show in the image...

[image: http://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-EuSQ3VCxSYs/T3n4mYuXftI/AAAAAAAAAX0/c5-Ood1s6Dg/s940/tabela.png]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

use `<ui:repeat>` over your email list, and print them inside e-mail column.

```
<ui:repeat var="email" value="#{user.emailList}">
#{email} <br/>
</ui:repeat>
```