# How to represent nested data in a Primefaces datatable?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

Here is my model :

**User.java**

```
public class User {
   //...

   public List<User> getFriends() {
      // ...
   }
}
```

I would like to build a table of user friends like this :

**users.jsf**

```
+----------+------------+
|   USER   |   FRIENDS  |
+----------+------------+
|          |    ALICE   |
|          +------------+        
|   ADAM   |    BOB     |
|          +------------+
|          |    PITT    |
+----------+------------+
|          |            |
....
```

Since there are many users, it's not possible to dump the user table in one go.

The datatable component is ideal in this case because it has built-in pagination support.
It is ideal too because it's possible to sort columns...

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find through the Primefaces examples a way for changing the rowspan in user columns.

How can I build this datatable ?

Some other OP having this similar issue:

- [Primefaces/JSF Nested Data Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610409/primefaces-jsf-nested-data-table)
- [How to do a dataTable containing a subtable with Primefaces in the same row? What's doing with mine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982944/how-to-do-a-datatable-containing-a-subtable-with-primefaces-in-the-same-row-wha?rq=1)
- [Primefaces dataTable with rowspan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139490/primefaces-datatable-with-rowspan)
- ... Add yours?

**EDIT**
Here is [the final solution I came up with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41747423/363573).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @Kerem's answer, here is the solution I came up with:

In order to make the nested datable like own rows of main datatable, I have overriden the CSS class `.ui-dt-c`. Check in `h:head` the `style` tag for details.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:head>
    <title>USERS and their friends</title>
    <style>
       .ui-dt-c {
          padding: 0px !important;
       }
    </style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form id="form">
<p:dataTable
    value="#{users.list}"
    var="u">

    <p:columnGroup type="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column headerText="USER" />
            <p:column headerText="FRIENDS" />
        </p:row>
    </p:columnGroup>

    <p:column>#{u.name}</p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:dataTable
            value="#{u.friends}"
            var="f">
            <p:column>#{f.name}</p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 14):

**Just use another data table inside your column :)**

```html
<h:column>
    <h:dataTable var="friend" value="#{user.friends}">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{friend.name}"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:column>
```

**This is how it looks on my localhost**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `ui:repeat` inside a column to get all the values of a collection.

Example:

```
<p:dataTable var="user" value="#{userGroupBacking.users}" id="userTable">

    <p:column headerText="User">
        <h:outputText value="#{user.name}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Groups">
        <ui:repeat var="group" value="#{user.groups}">
            <h:outputText value="#{group.name}" /><br />
        </ui:repeat>
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Primefaces [expandable rows](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableExpandableRows.jsf) should address your need, only you'll need to get creative with the child row component. You could use prime faces [data list component](http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dataListUnordered.jsf) as the child row component. It'll look something like:

```
   <p:row expansion>
    <p:datalist value ="#{yourTableRowVar.friendslist} Var="friend">
    #{friend.firstName}
    </p:datalist>
   </p:row expansion>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me there is two solution :

1- If i want to browse user by user and retrieve the list of friends, in this case i prefer the **dataList**.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{users.list}" var="u">

    <p:column headerText="USER">#{u.name}</p:column>    
    <p:column headerText="FRIENDS">
        <p:dataList value="#{u.friends}" var="f">
            #{f.name}
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

2- In a case where i can handle **directly the list of friends** (listFreinds [userName, friend]) or when i'm using **JPQL query** :

```
<p:dataTable value="#{users.listFreinds}" var="u" sortBy="#{u.userName}">

    <p:column headerText="USER" groupRow="true">#{u.userName}</p:column>    
    <p:column headerText="FRIENDS">#{u.friend}</p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

The second case, is a new native solution with **Primefaces Row Grouping** since v6.0.11

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/rowGroup.xhtml