# How to merge many cells in a column with same name into a single cell

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a datatable which displays records of country, state and district.

```
country | state | district
--------+-------+---------
ABC     | A     | Z
ABC     | A     | y
ABC     | A     | x
ABC     | B     | 1
ABC     | B     | 2
```

However, as you see in the example, the country is repeated over multiple rows. I would like to merge those into a single cell like so:

```
country | state | district
--------+-------+---------
ABC     | A     | Z
        | A     | y
        | A     | x
        | B     | 1
        | B     | 2
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649578/how-to-represent-nested-data-in-primefaces-datatable